# multiple popups in android

Tags: android, popup

I have two Linear Layouts in single activity .
I want to display custom popups on each of them when clicked.
When I click on first layout, popup apperas,then on clicking on 2nd layout ,both popups are displayed. how can i have only single popup displayed at a time?

this is my code

```
    workLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=          
   (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View popupView =   layoutInflater.inflate
    (R.layout.activity_your_places__work__popup, null);
     updateTextView = (TextView)    
     popupView.findViewById(R.id.UpdateTextView);
     updateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Your_Places2Activity.this,       
                    UpdateWorkAddressActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            deleteTextView = (TextView)     
            popupView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteTextView);
            deleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()                
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   //code to delete address
                }
            });
            popupWindowWork = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            //dismiss other popup if is showing
            if(popupWindowHome.isShowing())
            {
                popupWindowHome.dismiss();}
            //display popup
            popupWindowWork.showAsDropDown(workLinearLayout, 0, -70);

           }
         });
```

i have done same thing on other linear layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
popupWindowWork = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
if(popupWindowHome.isShowing())
{
    popupWindowHome.dismiss();
}
```

in this line, you are dismissing the `popupWindowHome` dialog if `popupWindowHome` is showing, with `popupWindowHome` being the NEW dialog. Move the if statement before the constructor call.

```
if(popupWindowHome != null && popupWindowHome.isShowing())
{
    popupWindowHome.dismiss();
}
popupWindowWork = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: thanks but still the app is crashing on click of any of the two linear layouts

Comment: @user4579047 Forgot to add a check to see if the dialog is null first. I edited my answer. If your app still crashes than please post what exception you get. (The reason for the crash might as well be unrelated)